# how do I send a GET request with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

Currently I am using Flask and Jquery and getting a 500 Internal Server Error response in my console. When I post with Ajax to the url on flask, shouldn't it be able to be received? I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Jquery

```
   $('.movie').click(function(){
       console.log(this);
         $(this).toggleClass('green blue').promise().done(function(){
            if ($(this).html() == "Add Movie"){
                $(this).html("Added");
            }
         });

        id = $(this).val();


        //get information from API
        $.ajax({
            url: "/profile",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            data: {id: id},
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
```

Python/Flask

```
@app.route("/profile", methods = ["GET"])
def profile(id):
    print("mydata is: ", request.args['id'])
    if request.args.get:
        print("this API is reached")
        id = request.args.get['id']
        url_movie = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{}?api_key=78cb6b67a99ce26e6d6619c617d9c907&language=en-US'.format(id)
        r = requests.get(url_movie)
        code = r.json();
        return jsonify(code)
```

[image: Error Console]

Comment: What's the error you're getting? You should be able to see this in the terminal in which you ran the flask server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 is a server error. There is something wrong with the request execution at server side only.

Comment: debug ur server script to get the answer